# Display contents of a column on a different cell

Tags: function, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet in which I have points for different students. Every week I will be sending out an email from the spreadsheet to the students informing them of their current points and name of students with the maximum points. I was able to work everything out, except for the last part. I am unable to display all the names of students having the maximum points in the message. Please find [my spreadsheet here.](http://goo.gl/6uihEP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to join the result of the list outputted by your filter function in one cell (D2) and then reference that cell in your message.

```
=JOIN(", ", FILTER(A2:A,B2:B=MAX(B2:B)))
```

You can even have the last comma replaced with 'and' and add a point at the end...

```
=regexreplace(JOIN(", ", FILTER(A2:A,B2:B=MAX(B2:B))), ",\s(\w+)$", " and $1.")
```

so it complets the message body you already have..

See if that works ?